# Displaying a background-image with a longblob data from my MySQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to insert a image from my database on phpmyadmin and I'm gettin a situation where it just doesnt show my image. The type I'm using on my table is a longblob because my image is bigger. Is there any way I could fix this output so I can just output my image?

NOTE : It seems everything else works EXCEPT for the image part, I just felt like showing the whole php code just in case

HTML / PHP

```
            if ($result-> num_rows > 0) {
                while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo "<div class='service-title'>";
                    echo "<h2>". $row["serviceName"] ."</h2>";
                    echo "</div>";
                    
                    echo "<a href=". $row["servicePageName"] .">";
                    echo '<div class="service-container" style="background-image: data:image/jpg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['serviceImage']).'"/>';
                    echo "<h1>Click Me!</h1>";
                    echo "</div>";
                    echo "</a>";
                }
            }
            $conn-> close();
```

Comment: I can tell that your `div` opening tag is missing a `>` at the end, and it looks like it has an extra `)`, possibly a missing `"`, too.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Haas yeah I switched up the code, I got to a spot where the text doesn't appear but the image doesnt appear either, I'll update the code if you'd like to look at it

Comment: your database is on a mysql server... phpmyadmin is just a tool to display the data

Comment: @LelioFaieta have the database on the phpmyadmin website, everytime outputs correctly, my image is just not showing. I've done this with tables aswell and it worked, so Idk why the image is not displaying.

Comment: Can you remove everything and only run `echo base64_encode($row['serviceImage'])` and show the output? And can you do this with just a small sample image for demonstration purposes.

Comment: @ChrisHass Pasting that command within my while statement I get this: https://gyazo.com/63404862ef805c671e47b14b6ddecae1

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out by just adding a simple url() into the background-image